# bootstrap nav focus and hover won't change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking in the devtools and it is revealing the following code:

```
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

The problem is, I change these in my css file and it won't let me get rid of the grey background color. How can I override it?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ended up being a ui-router issue, not a css issue. Sorry everyone, thanks for the troubleshooting. Changed:

```
<li ng-class="{active: stateis('app.contact')}"  ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="app.contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Contact</a>
</li>
```

To this:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="app.contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Contact</a>
</li>
```

And is fixed

Comment: Can you add more details. These CSS rules, where are these specified? In your code or did you import some third party library.

Comment: I added Bootstrap. And in devtools it appears as though the line of background-color:#eee is struck out, but it shows up when I click on a button and move my mouse cursor out of the button. I want it to remain solid blue. So I added the same code as above to my css and changed the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ">" after nav class. Please Try this :

```
.nav li>a:focus, .nav li>a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Check out [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/gLx5foe7/)

Comment: I will give it a try tonight. Thanks.

Comment: didn't fix the issue. Still getting a eee background when I rollout of the .nav button.

Comment: I found the issue, it ended up not being a css issue, but a ui-router issue.